# VB.NET - Hook mechanism, or how to execute a list of methods?

Tags: vb.net

I have an algorithm that "always" runs steps A, C, D in that order.

I want to allow a way to run A, B, C, D, where B can be multiple methods. C, D "should" be unaffected, but I cannot parallelize it. It is just writing to a file.

Any way, I know a tiny bit about delegates and have used the AddressOf to hook up an event handler.

So I was thinking of simply creating an array or collection of what not of "addresses" or delegates.

Is this even possible?

Is this the 'best' way? I know how to force the behavior with objects, but I am hoping to reuse any mechanisms already built in to VB, .NET.

Dane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use an event to store and invoke multiple methods. Events are basically streamlined multicast delegates, so you won't have to use `Delegate.Combine`. The drawback is that your methods won't be able to have return types.

Here's an alternative way to use multicast delegates, as well. This example assumes you want a value to be returned from the methods. If you don't need this, you won't have to loop through the methods; you can just use `myMethods.Invoke`.

```
'the methods will be stored here
Private _MyMethods As [Delegate]

'this is here to show the signature of the methods
Public Delegate Function MyMethod(ByVal input As String) As String

Public Sub AddMethod(ByVal method As MyMethod)
    _MyMethods = [Delegate].Combine(_MyMethods, method)
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveMethod(ByVal method As MyMethod)
    _MyMethods = [Delegate].Remove(_MyMethods, method)
End Sub

Public Sub InvokeMethods(ByVal input As String)
    If _MyMethods Is Nothing Then Return

    Dim myMethods As MyMethod = DirectCast(_MyMethods, MyMethod)

    'since you'll want the return value of each methods, loop through the methods
    For Each method As MyMethod In myMethods.GetInvocationList()
        Dim value As String = method.Invoke(input)

        'TODO: something with the value
    Next
End Sub
```

As another alternative to that invocation code above, you could use the `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` method to not have to cast the delegate. That, however, would use late-binding, and, in the case of a function, would require the return value to be cast anyway.

Comment: Learned both from Gideon Engelberth and Timiz0r, but had to choose one. Thanks gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you see often, but you can combine delegates so that a single delegate variable calls multiple functions when invoked.

```
Dim midAction As Action(Of String) = AddressOf Console.WriteLine
Dim m1 As New IO.StreamWriter(New IO.MemoryStream())
m1.AutoFlush = True
Dim m2 As New IO.StreamWriter(New IO.MemoryStream())
midAction = CType([Delegate].Combine(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf Console.WriteLine),
                                     New Action(Of String)(AddressOf m1.WriteLine),
                                     New Action(Of String)(Sub(s)
                                                             m2.WriteLine(s)
                                                             m2.Flush()
                                                           End Sub)), 
                  Action(Of String))
 midAction("test")
```

The biggest downer here is that the typelessness of `Delegate.Combine` makes all the casting necessary.

An `IEnumerable` of delegates would also work and more strongly conveys that you *want* to call multiple functions.

From your description, I think I would stick to a single delegate parameter as it seems to be a better match for the semantics of the argument. The caller can do the combining when they have multiple functions that need to be called in the middle.